# Use Spring as nested expression for resource bundle?

Tags: java, spring, jsf

Lets assume I would use Spring to handle my resrouce bundle. Would the following be possible?

```
<h:commandButton value="<spring:message value="label.execute" />" />
```

Or can I save my time diggin into this?

(I know I could use `value="#{message['label.execute']}"` instead...)

tx